# My android application closes when moving to another activity

Tags: android, sqlite

i'm new here and new to programming in general

I'm creating a blood donation android application with SQLite and when i move to another activity to display the donors it closes.

I created a database using DB Helper Here is the code:

```
public class BloodBankDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "Bloodbank";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    BloodBankDatabaseHelper (Context context){

        super(context, "Bloodbank", null, 1 );
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE DONOR ("
        + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + "NAME TEXT,"
        + "BLOOD TEXT, "
        + "PHONE TEXT, " + " DISTRICT TEXT"
        + " EMAIL TEXT);");

        insertDonor(db, "Bilal Achi", "O+", "03567773", "Beirut", "bilal.achi@hotmail.com");
        insertDonor(db, "Mohamad", "O-", "03024026","Beirut",  "Mohamad@hotmail.com");
        insertDonor(db, "Fadi", "A-", "03444333","Beirut", "Fadi211@hotmail.com");
        insertDonor(db, "Hadi", "B-", "03123122", "Beirut", "Hadi@hotmail.com");
        insertDonor(db, "Rana", "AB+", "03974267", "Beirut", "Rana121@hotmail.com");
        insertDonor(db, "Sara", "A+", "03123891", "Beirut", "Sarah@hotmail.com");
        insertDonor(db, "Khalil", "B-", "03456189", "Beirut", "Khalil088@hotmail.com");
        insertDonor(db, "Jad", "O-", "03999211", "Tyre", "Jad992@hotmail.com");
        insertDonor(db, "Siham", "AB+", "03213477", "Tyre", "Siham1112@hotmail.com");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "DONOR");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    private static void insertDonor(SQLiteDatabase db, String name, String blood, String phone,
                                   String disctrict, String email) {

        ContentValues donorValues = new ContentValues();
        donorValues.put("NAME",name);
        donorValues.put("BLOOD", blood);
        donorValues.put("PHONE", phone);
        donorValues.put("Email", email);
        donorValues.put("DISTRICT",disctrict);
        db.insert("DONOR", null, donorValues );
    }
}
```

My main activity consists of two spinner to specify the district and blood type and a button to move to the activity

Here is the Code for the main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SQLiteDatabase db;


    private Spinner sp1;
    private Spinner sp2;
    private Button bt1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sp1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spnr1);
        sp2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spnr2);
        bt1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);

        String[] Districts = {"Aley ","Akkar ","Baabda ","Baalback ","Batroun ","Beirut ",
                "Bsharri ","Chouf ","Hasbaya ","Hermel ","Jbeil ","Jizzine ","Keserwan ",
                "Koura ", "Marjeyoun ","Matn ","Miniyeh-Danniyeh ","Nabatieh ","Rashaya ","Sydon ",
                "Tripoli ","Tyre ","Western Bekaa ","Zahle ","Zgharta "};

        String [] BloodTypes = {"O+ ", "O- ","A+ ","A- ","B+ ",
        "B- ","AB+ ","AB- "};

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, Districts);
        sp1.setAdapter(adapter);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, BloodTypes);
        sp2.setAdapter(adapter2);

        sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String Districts = sp1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String bloodtypes = sp2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Donor.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Now when the button is pressed a new activity should start displaying the donors but the application crashes Here is the code

```
public class Donor extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String Extra_Disctrict = "Districts";
    public static final String Extra_type = "bloodtypes";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_donor);

    String Districts = (String)getIntent().getExtras().get(Extra_Disctrict);
    String bloodtypes = (String)getIntent().getExtras().get(Extra_type);


    //Create a Cursor

    try {
        SQLiteOpenHelper BloodBankDatabaseHelper = new BloodBankDatabaseHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = BloodBankDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query("Bloodbank",
                new String[]{"NAME", "PHONE", "EMAIL"},
                "DISTRICT = ? AND BLOOD = ?",
                new String []{(Districts),(bloodtypes)}, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            String nameText = cursor.getString(0);
            String phoneText = cursor.getString(1);
            String emailText = cursor.getString(2);

            TextView name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
            name.setText(nameText);

            TextView phone = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.phone);
            phone.setText(phoneText);
            TextView email = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.email);
            email.setText(emailText);

        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

    } catch(SQLiteException e) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Database unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the Logcat

```
01-19 00:10:03.491 3316-3316/? E/AndroidRuntime: in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.example.bilal.bloodbank
01-19 00:10:03.521 3316-3316/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.example.bilal.bloodbank, PID: 3316
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bilal.bloodbank/com.example.bilal.bloodbank.Donor}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                     at com.example.bilal.bloodbank.Donor.onCreate(Donor.java:24)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5397)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643) 
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
01-19 00:10:04.171 4174-4174/? E/AndroidRuntime: in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.example.bilal.bloodbank
01-19 00:10:04.201 4174-4174/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.example.bilal.bloodbank, PID: 4174
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bilal.bloodbank/com.example.bilal.bloodbank.Donor}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                     at com.example.bilal.bloodbank.Donor.onCreate(Donor.java:24)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5397)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643) 
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
01-19 00:10:04.741 4186-4186/? E/AndroidRuntime: in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.example.bilal.bloodbank
01-19 00:10:04.761 4186-4186/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.example.bilal.bloodbank, PID: 4186
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bilal.bloodbank/com.example.bilal.bloodbank.Donor}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                     at com.example.bilal.bloodbank.Donor.onCreate(Donor.java:24)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5397)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643) 
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
01-19 00:10:11.361 1773-4205/system_process E/ActivityManager: Exception in bstSendTopActivityInfo while sending HttpPost: Connect to /10.0.2.2:2861 timed out
```

Your help would be highly Appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Assuming you are using Android Studio and the device is connected to your PC, you should see a pretty clear reason for the crash in Android Studio's LogCat window.  Filter LogCat to Errors and you will likely find it.  If you find it but don't understand it, add the LogCat entry to your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying, I looked at the Logcat window and filtered it to errors but couldn't really understand. i added the Logcat to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important part of your LogCat entry is

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.example.bilal.bloodbank.Donor.onCreate(Donor.java:24)

Line 24 of Donor.java

```
String Districts = (String)getIntent().getExtras().get(Extra_Disctrict);
```

is trying to get Districts out of the Intent extras Bundle but getExtras() is returning null. Your main activity code is not adding any extras to the intent:

```
String Districts = sp1.getSelectedItem().toString();
String bloodtypes = sp2.getSelectedItem().toString();
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Donor.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Add your Strings to the intent extras before calling startActivity.

```
intent.putExtra("Districts", Districts);
intent.putExtra("bloodtypes", bloodtypes);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, Now the application is not crashing but I'm getting that the Database is unavailable, Any help?

Comment: Happy to help.  Your question wasn't bad.  The down votes were a little  harsh and likely because you were initially missing the error details.  Error details are always most important along with relevant code instead of all of your code...but it can be difficult to know what code is relevant to the question, especially when you are new, so erring on the side of too much is fine.

Comment: @BilalAshi you should really ask a new question. However this line `+ "PHONE TEXT, " + " DISTRICT TEXT"` is incorrect as you have another column (EMAIL) so there should be a comma following the DISTRICT column definition i.e. the line should be `+ "PHONE TEXT, " + " DISTRICT TEXT,"` (comma after TEXT, **the end of the DISTRICT column definition**)

Comment: @BilalAshi, after fixing the above the database unavailable is because there is no table named **Bloodbank** log has `01-19 01:03:34.383 1212-1212/bloodbank.bilal.example.com.myapplication E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: Bloodbank`, rather I believe you should be specifying **DONOR** as the table (*Bloodbank is the database name*). I'd suggest adding `public static final String TB_DONOR = "DONOR";` and always referring to that e.g. `Cursor cursor = db.query(BloodBankDatabaseHelper.TB_DONOR,......` However as you've called the instance the same name as the class this won't work ....more

Comment: I'd suggest renaming the instance of the **BloodBankDatabaseHelper** e.g. change (refactor/rename) so the two lines are `SQLiteOpenHelper bloodBankDatabaseHelper = new BloodBankDatabaseHelper(this);
            SQLiteDatabase db = bloodBankDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();`. Then you can use `Cursor cursor = db.query(BloodBankDatabaseHelper.TB_DONOR,......` (where ..... represents the rest of the code.). As such you have 1 definition that is used throughout thus reducing the likelihood of mistakes. Suggest you do the same for column names.

Comment: @MikeT you are absolutely amazing, I really cant that you enough

Comment: @BilalAshi my pleasure and thanks for the compliment.